# Non-functioning disk image on SSD but working on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, ssd, clone, macrium

I recently tried to upgrade a laptop by replacing the HDD by an SSD, but I am running into some trouble.

**Background**: I am fairly familiar with cloning and disk imaging (I use Macrium Reflect and have successfully upgraded desktops and laptops using this program such that I am certain the program is reliable).

**Description of the issue**: after a successful image and deployment from the HDD to the SSD, Windows boots, I am able to launch Chrome, but the computer refuses to take any click (either left or right click) with mouse or mousepad, making it unusable. Input with letters works fine. The computer works fine with the HDD, so the issue is only due to using an HDD vs an SSD.

**What I did**:

- From a 500GB HDD, squeezed the partition to 250GB with `diskmgmt.msc`
- With Macrium Reflect, I imaged all the partitions but the Recovery partition to the new disk (SSD).
- Resized the OS partition on the SSD with `diskmgmt.msc` to allow for a new partition that will host the Recovery partition
- Imaged the Recovery partition from the HDD to the newly created volume on the SSD.
- Swapped the HDD for the SSD. Windows boots, loads Chrome very fast, so OK.

**How I would go about troubleshooting**: I realized that this may have been a lot of resizing from two different programs and that the copy is not a perfect copy and somehow messed up with Windows. I have therefore used the built-in function of Macrium to resize the partition *before* making the clone. This is currently running.

**Potentially useful information**:

- the computer is a Lenovo B4500 running Windows 8, i5-4200M
- the HDD is a 500GB drive
- the SSD is a Kingston A400 of 250GB
- I would prefer to avoid reinstalling Windows, but I have recovered the product key and ID just in case. The license is, of course, an OEM version.

**Question**: would an upgrade to Windows 10 solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a driver issue. First, open Device Manager:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `devmgmt.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, if needed, to focus on the list of devices.
- Use the up and down arrow keys, <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>, to select `Mice and other pointing devices`.
- Use the left and right arrow keys, <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, to select any device with an error indicator.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the `Properties` dialog.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the `Driver` tab.
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select `Update Driver`.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to find drivers on the internet.
- If that fails to find a driver, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to close the update dialog, then follow the above direction for update, but select `Uninstall Device`.

After rebooting, Windows usually finds the correct driver.

Another way to repair drivers uses the commands [SFC and DISM to find and replace missing or damaged files](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image).

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `Yes` to get a CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter `SFC /scannow`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and wait for the System File Check to finish.
- Enter `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and wait for the scan to finish.
- Enter `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and wait for attempted repairs to finish.

If all previous attempts failed, then [download the Windows 10 ISO and put it on a USB flash drive using the media creation tool.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) (not available for Windows 10 Enterpise, though). Perform an in-place update, keeping your current files. Since you have the original image on the HDD, at the worst, you can recover from this if there's an issue.

*BTW, kudos for providing good diagnostic info!*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. In fact, the problem came from my own stupidity: when replacing the HDD by the SSD, I was not able to remove the HDD from its tray and therefore placed a small support inside the laptop to prevent the SSD from wobbling. However, this small support was conductive and messed up the mouse input. Replacing the support by a non-conductive one fixed the issue. I nevertheless accept your answer as my problem may very well have been a driver issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the cautionary message about hardware mods.